# Java: NoSuchMethodError when using getters and setters to access private variables from another class

Tags: java, getter-setter

-I am understanding working of getters and setters in java. I am trying to access private variables(id, name) of other class through -methods like getName(),setName(). but my main method is not able to detect these methods and gives

> error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Employee.setName(java.lang.String)'
> at getterssetters_41.main(getterssetters_41.java:5)

This is my main class:

```
public  class getterssetters_41 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        String anurag="Anurag";
        emp1.setName(anurag);
        System.out.println(emp1.getName());
        emp1.setId(1);
        System.out.println(emp1.getId());
   }
}
```

> //This is class which have variables and methods I want to access

```
class Employee {
    private int id;
    private  String name;
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }
    public void setId(int i){
        id = i;
    }    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

'

Comment: As per this [live demo](https://ideone.com/rYORy6), your code works. Use an IDE (I recommend IntelliJ) which will help you keep everything compiled.

Answer (score 2):

That error is not possible unless you have done the following:

- You have compiled your code the way it was *before* you added those getters/setters.
- You then added them and (re)compiled everything. However, to a new location. Or, you have recompiled only your main class, with the changed (but not yet recompiled!) Employee source file on the sourcepath.
- You are now running the class file created by compiling `main` **after** your update, with the Employee class file created by compiling `Employee` **before** it.

Solution: Recompile everything.

`NoSuchMethodError` can only occur if a method does exist when you compile your code but no longer exists at runtime - i.e. when you are mixing compilation output from different runs together (or, if it's not within your own code, you have compiled against version X of some library but at runtime version Y is on the classpath, or both X and Y are on the classpath resulting in an arbitrary one being used at runtime).

Comment: I got solution, I changed name of class. I guess it doesn't allow duplicate class in same folder.